# pulumi yaml file to set config in values.yaml

Tags: datadog, pulumi, pulumi-python

I´m qite new at pulumi (I´m more a terraform guy).
I´m working in a legacy code which deploys helm charts into kubernetes. (splunk, Datadog, etc).
They are using python for this.
In code I see that they have a pulumi.[env].chart_name to pass some values I believe.
Like follows:

```
config:
  kubernetes:context: my-aks-cluster
  toolbase:baseStack: dev.sandbox
  toolbase:cluster-name: aks-foo-123
  toolbase:cluster-tags: aks-foo-123
  toolbase:datadog-logLevel: DEBUG
  tooling:some other value.....
```

in some other python file I see they use a values option to override parameters using for example: ""logLevel": config.require('datadog-logLevel')," and they override that with the yaml file that I previous showed.

```
values={
            "nameOverride": "",
            "fullnameOverride": "",
            "targetSystem": "linux",
            "datadog": {
                "apiKey": datadog_creds.data.get('api-key'),
                "logLevel": config.require('datadog-logLevel'),
                "securityContext": {},
```

My question is How this actually works? I want to now use the yaml file to pass some key:value pairs for some pod labels in the values.yaml file but I´m not sure how to do this with an object type.
for exxample:

toolbase:podlabels: {label1:foo, label2:bar, labelx:some othervalue}

is this possible?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep -- take a look at the docs on [structured configuration](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/concepts/config/#structured-configuration). You're most likely looking for either `get_object()` or `require_object()`.

The following Python program, for example, fetches an object from the selected stack's configuration file and uses it to apply some tags to an S3 bucket:

```py
import pulumi
from pulumi_aws import s3

config = pulumi.Config()
bucket_tags = config.require_object("bucket_tags")

pulumi.log.info(bucket_tags["tag_1"])
pulumi.log.info(bucket_tags["tag_2"])

bucket = s3.Bucket("my-bucket", s3.BucketArgs(
    tags=bucket_tags,
))

pulumi.export("bucket_name", bucket.id)
```

To set the object's data, you have a couple of options. With the CLI, you can use `pulumi config set` with the `--path` option to define the object's structure and data:

```bash
pulumi config set --path "bucket_tags.tag_1" "value1"
pulumi config set --path "bucket_tags.tag_2" "value2"
```

This'll give you a `Pulumi.<stack-name>.yaml` file that looks something like this:

```yaml
config:
  aws:region: us-west-2
  my-project:bucket_tags:
    tag_1: value1
    tag_2: value2
```

Alternatively, you could write these values directly into the YAML file yourself. This is fine, too, so long as what you write is valid YAML object syntax.

The result, after `pulumi up`:

```
$ pulumi up

Updating (dev)

     Type                 Name             Status           Info
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack  my-project-dev   created (3s)     2 messages
 +   └─ aws:s3:Bucket     my-bucket        created (2s)     

Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (my-project-dev):
    value1
    value2

Outputs:
    bucket_name: "my-bucket-bd67797"

Resources:
    + 2 created

Duration: 4s
```

[image: The tags applied to the s3]

Hope that helps!